# Swing Table - sorting numbers is wrong (uses toString representation)

Tags: swing, scala, jtable, tablerowsorter

I'm baffled by a Scala-Swing `Table` not correctly sorting numbers when setting `t.peer.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`.

This is from my table model:

```
  override def getColumnClass(colIdx: Int): Class[_] =
    (colIdx: @switch) match {
      case 0 => classOf[Int]
      case 1 => classOf[String]
      case 2 => classOf[Double]
    }
```

But it appears the first and third column are sorted by string representation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mismatch with primitive types and Java expecting `AnyRef` instances. The following works:

```
  override def getColumnClass(colIdx: Int): Class[_] =
    (colIdx: @switch) match {
      case 0 => classOf[java.lang.Integer]
      case 1 => classOf[String]
      case 2 => classOf[java.lang.Double]
    }
```